# Visual Studio Remote debug error 7b

Tags: visual-c++, remote-debugging

On some systems, we are running into error 0x0007b using VS Remote Debugger. The error is triggered after loading some local libraries. It looks like runtimes and other DLLs in the local SYSWOW64 are not found.

Other systems similarly configured do not show that error.

Reinstalling runtimes and rebooting do not solve this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution. In this case, there was the wrong set of Qt DLLs installed. This was a 32 Bit app and the ones installed were 64 bit.
The apps have the same name, so there was no error of DLL not found.